# Can I run tsc on a specific file and automatically include tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsc

### Background

I have a typescript file and tsconfig.json in the same directory:

index.ts:

```
function foo(bar) {
    bar.buzz = 100;
}

let obj = { x: 0 };
obj.bar = 100;
```

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true
    }
}
```

If I run `npx tsc -p tsconfig.json`, I get 2 errors, which is what I expect.

If I run `npx tsc index.ts`, I only get 1 error.

### My Question

Is there a way to run `npx tsc index.ts` (or similar) and have it pick up the tsconfig file?

If so, how do I do it?

If not, why not? I'm new to typescript and trying to understand how everything is connected.

For what it's worth, from my reviewing of the [tsconfig doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), and various other searching around, it seems like you cannot run `npx tsc index.ts` and have it pick up the tsconfig file:

> A project is compiled in one of the following ways:
>
> - By invoking tsc with no input files, in which case the compiler  searches for the `tsconfig.json` file starting in the current directory and continuing up the parent directory chain.
> - By invoking tsc with no input files and a `--project` (or just `-p`) command line option that specifies the path of a directory containing a `tsconfig.json` file, or a path to a valid `.json` file containing the configurations.
>
> **When input files are specified on the command line, `tsconfig.json` files are ignored.**

Nevertheless, it would be useful to have my guess confirmed by someone more experienced.

### (Optional-ish: Additional details)

#### Environment details:

```
$ node -v
v18.19.0
$ npx tsc -v
Version 5.3.3
```

OS: MacOS Catalina (10.15.7)

#### Full `tsc` command outputs

```
$ npx tsc index.ts
index.ts:6:5 - error TS2339: Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{ x: number; }'.

6 obj.bar = 100;
      ~~~


Found 1 error in index.ts:6
```

```
$ npx tsc -p tsconfig.json 
index.ts:1:14 - error TS7006: Parameter 'bar' implicitly has an 'any' type.

1 function foo(bar) {
               ~~~

index.ts:6:5 - error TS2339: Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{ x: number; }'.

6 obj.bar = 100;
      ~~~


Found 2 errors in the same file, starting at: index.ts:1
```

```
$ npx tsc
index.ts:1:14 - error TS7006: Parameter 'bar' implicitly has an 'any' type.

1 function foo(bar) {
               ~~~

index.ts:6:5 - error TS2339: Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{ x: number; }'.

6 obj.bar = 100;
      ~~~


Found 2 errors in the same file, starting at: index.ts:1
```

Comment: There is an open GitHub issue tracking this request: [microsoft/TypeScript#27379](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27379)

Comment: @jsejcksn Great link, the critical bit I didn't understand was in a [comment there](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27379#issuecomment-424879463) *"When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored"*. So running `tsc` on its own will use the `tsconfig.json` (and go searching parent directories), but running `tsc index.ts` will ignore the `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `npx tsc -p tsconfig.json`, TypeScript compiles all files in the context of `tsconfig.json`, applying the configurations specified in there. That is why you see two errors, since the `strict` option in `tsconfig.json` enforces stricter type-checking.
You can see an example in ["Publishing Node modules with TypeScript and ES modules"](https://blog.logrocket.com/publishing-node-modules-typescript-es-modules/#compiling-typescript) from [Jack Franklin](https://github.com/jackfranklin) .

But, when you run `npx tsc index.ts`, TypeScript compiles only `index.ts`, *without* considering `tsconfig.json`. That is the reason you see only one error; the `strict` option is not applied.

Currently, there is no direct way to run [`tsc`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) on a single file and have it automatically include the settings from `tsconfig.json`. When you specify a file, `tsc` bypasses the project context created by `tsconfig.json`.

One workaround is to use project references or a build script that includes `tsconfig.json` and the specific file you want to compile. For instance, you can create a script that alters `tsconfig.json` to include only `index.ts` in the [`"files"` array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#files) before running `tsc`.

And you should also update `index.ts` to fix the errors:

```js
interface Bar {
    buzz?: number;
}

function foo(bar: Bar) {
    bar.buzz = 100;
}

let obj = { x: 0, bar: 100 };
```